# How to think of the unit $\rm eV$?

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, dimensional-analysis, units

How to get a sense of $\rm eV$? I mean when I know how much a metre is or a second is, but how to "visualize" when it is said atomic reactions are in order of $\rm eV$ and nuclear reactions are in order of $\rm MeV$? Should I just remember it?

Comment: Basically, yes. The more you work with stuff, the easier it gets until it is second nature.

Comment: Besides what Jon said did you read what it is? It's really not much different than a Joule save for sense of scale in comparison to the situations it is used in.

Comment: Do you understand why it’s a unit of energy? This is probably more important than trying to visualize an amount of energy that is tiny even compared to the kinetic energy of, say, a fly.

Comment: I understand that it is used instead of joule as elementary particles have "tiny" energy compared to joule. i mean i know the way its defined, but "why a unit of energy" -i dont know what to say to that

Comment: It takes $qV$ energy to move a charge $q>0$ through a potential difference $V>0$. It's just multiplying the positron's charge by one volt.

Comment: Yea as i said i know the definition..

Comment: Perhaps consider the energy (in joules) of a mole of electrons that each have KE of 1 eV.

Comment: The electric potential at a distance of one Bohr radius from a proton is 27 volts. So charge-of-electron ($-e$) times 27 volts is the electron’s electrostatic potential energy in the ground state of hydrogen, -27 eV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volt originated as a unit in electrochemistry: it's the scale of EMF that a battery makes. At the atomic level, most chemical reactions proceed one electron or ion at a time, so eV is the atomic energy scale for chemical reactions.

Not coincidentally, this is also the energy scale for visible photons, since vision depends on photochemistry. The atomic physics of outer shell electrons probes this same range. So, if you're doing chemistry, photonics, or atomic physics, eV are reasonable units.

The extension to keV, MeV, GeV, TeV is partly historical, as x-ray and nuclear physics grew from atomic physics, and then particle physics grew from nuclear physics. But it also reflects that we use atomic processes to detect energetic particles. A silicon ionization detector averages 1 electron-hole pair generated per 3.6 eV of energy deposited, so a 1 MeV alpha particle will yield about 280,000 electrons in a diode detector.

This grounding in reality is what makes eV an important unit for physics.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, all of these different units of energy have their particular story and sense of meaning, e.g. *horsepower* is a quantification of the amount of power it takes for a stout horse to lift a certain amount of weight in a certain amount of time. To really understand a particular unit it helps to understand the particular story behind it.

For the electron volt, the story is that given a potential difference of 1-volt, the electron volt is the amount of kinetic energy that is gained by an electron, initially at rest, as it accelerates across a potential difference of exactly 1-volt in vacuum. So what about a MeV? That is the energy gained by just such an electron as it accelerates across a difference of one million volts, and so on for units like GeV and TeV. At any rate, if you apply the work energy to the electron (treating it as a point particle) for the acceleration across 1V, according to the description above, you get that the eV is just about $1.6\times 10^{-19}$ Joules.

If you are looking for some sense of familiarity with the eV as a unit of energy, then good luck, because, it is a tiny amount of energy, you wouldn't likely notice it any more than an electron itself. With some units there is no way to get familiar in the sense that one can with centimeters, etc.